# Modular functionality with ASP.NET vNext Core CLR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kruntime

With ASP.NET 4.5 it is possible to use `Assembly.Load()` or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load()` to dynamically load an assembly at runtime. This can be used to add new functionality to a running web application in the form of modules without having to rebuild or even restart the app.

I would like to know how this can be done with the new ASP.NET vNext (5.0?) targeting the Core framework. I know this can be done with the full framework as `System.AppDomain` is available along with an overloaded `Assembly.Load()`. When I change to target the Core framework, I no longer have `System.AppDomain` available and `Assembly.Load()` becomes limited.

Is there a way to get this dynamic modular functionality in the ASP.NET 5.0 Core framework?

Comment: Regardless of vNext, you may want to take a look at MEF (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I have already considered MEF and it doesn't appear to be available in the core framework. Neither `System.ComponentModel.Composition` or `System.Compostion` appear to be available.

Comment: I have the same task now. Do you have any ideas ho to do that? How do you think, maybe we can use dynamic compilation instead of features like MEF?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what a good answer would be, because Asp.Net 5 is so new, and doesn't have a lot of full documentation.

It should theoretically be possible, it'll just be different than what you're used to.

Looking at the source there is an interface [IAssemblyLoadContext](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions/IAssemblyLoadContext.cs) which will allow you to get the assembly.   There is also [IAssemblyLoader](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions/IAssemblyLoader.cs).

These are used by the "kre" host, which is the underlying piece of Asp.Net 5 that basically boostraps your application.  So you would need to add your `IAssemblyLoader` to the underlying host, so that the kre.

Unfortunately I'm not seeing very many extension points in the code as of yet.   Will we be getting those extension points?  I do not know.  You can log an issue on the [github](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues) page.   It's also possible there is an extension point I'm not seeing currently.

To come back to the question, can you add that kind of extensiblity to Asp.Net 5 Core?  Yes, you could create your own host, similar to the default host, that would then include your custom loader, and then start your application with that.

Comment: Thanks David, this is a very different approach! I'll have a dig in the source and see what I can find.

Comment: I think there is already an [issue logged for this](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/500), so I guess it is  still to come

Answer (score 1):

You can try [***ExtCore***](https://github.com/ExtCore/ExtCore)  framework

It allows to have modular and extendable **ASP.NET 5** applications out of the box.

**In short**

1. It allows to use both modules from dlls and from nuget packages at the same time.
2. It allows all modules to work with storage in the single context and to have their own models and repositories.
3. Every extension can have controllers, views, static content etc.